# Website showing small on iPhone

Tags: iphone, responsive-design, viewport, ebay-design-templates

I've developing a store on eBay and having trouble with it on iPhones...

It seems to be nicely responsive in a normal browser, but when I view it on an iPhone it only takes up about half of the screen...

Is there something I'm missing?

The URL is http://stores.ebay.co.uk/the-biggest-toy-store

I've added a viewport tag like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Thanks!

Comment: If i remove the viewport tag it loads the site in full, so it's not responsive to smaller sizes..  

if I put it back in it responds like it's 414px wide (viewed on iPhone 6 plus) but only in half the screen...  

I guess it's something to do with the retina screen, but it's all set to 100% width so should just fit the screen....

Comment: using inspect element in Chrome always helps me solve mobile / responsive issues like this, especially if you use the mobile view (small phone icon in top left of developer tools screen).  It will show what is "shooting off the screen", and allows you to check different screen sizes very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I noticed in your site, remove the min-width: 760px from your .stBadge (in your media query only).  That will help get the footer within the screen boundary.  There is also some kind of border up top that has a wider-than-screen width, possible the #gh-top div... but that may be fixed once the other is.

Comment: Thank you...   I had already removed and overriden a few styles that were already there on the eBay style sheets... I did a simple overflow:hidden on one section that helped out!

Answer (score 2):

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">`

in your index.html page and it should work

Comment: That's almost the same as I had, except with the maximum scale added.. I've changed to that now and it's not made a difference...